# Do CALayers block Touch Events in underlying views?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-animation

I have an application with a view containing several subviews.  The subviews did not implement any touchesbegins logic.  The Superview implemented all touchesbegins logic and manipulated each subview respectively if it was touched (determined by hit testing).

I have since been converting my subviews to layers.  My problem now is that if I touch a layer, the hosting view of the superlayer never gets the touchesbegins method called.  However if I touch the background, the touchesbegin method fires.

I understood from documentation that layers cannot handle events, if this is so why would it block events to the hosting view?

Thanks for any help, can't get my head around this.

-Corey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CALayers should not block touch events. Is your `userInteractionEnabled` flag set in the hosting view (sounds like it is, if you're getting SOME touches)? Is it inside a UIScrollView, which may be doing its own touch-handling.

Comment: Ben this I my first post here, I'm not sure if I am supposed to post my responses as answers or as a comment to your answer. Hopefully I did it right.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem... I was releasing the sublayers I was creating using [CALayer layer].  Since I didn't have control of them, I shouldn't have been managing them.

Answer (score 0):

What class is your touchesBegan method in?
I was having a similiar problem because my touchesBegan method was in a UIView subclass.
After moving the method to a UIViewController subclass, my problem was fixed.

Try doing that.